# Почему отсутствует цвет текста в TextBox?

Tags: wpf

**Разметка**

```
TextBlock Margin="10 0 0 0">Логин</TextBlock>
            
            <TextBox Margin="0 10 0 0"   Name="tBLogin"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 20 0">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=tBLogin}" Value="30">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=tBLogin, Mode=OneWay}"/>/<Run Text="{Binding MaxLength, ElementName=tBLogin}"/>
            </TextBlock>
```

**Стиль**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                        
                        CornerRadius="20"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        
                        Background="{TemplateBinding  Background}">
                     
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
    </Style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у вас в стиле контент? Вы ему `Border` задали с нужными цветами и все, а "внутренности" где?

Comment: **<ContentPresenter
                            
                                x:Name="myContent"
                                Foreground="DarkBlue"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            </ContentPresenter>**
Ну даже если я ему это пропишу, он не поддерживает   Foreground. Как тогда цвет указать ?

Comment: А я про этот контент вам говорил? Посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#textbox-controltemplate-example), посмотрите, как устроен шаблон стандартного контрола, да даже в студии, нажмите на контрол без стиля правой кнопкой мыши и там выберите "Правка шаблона", он вам создат все необходимое.